# how to copy a file to capistrano shared folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have file `config/secrets.yml` which has to be in my remote server in the shared folder. And it is not in my git repo, so it's not updated as other regular files.

I don't know how generate file the first time.

What I have done till the moment is to create a symlink each time I deploy with

```
run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
```

which will "update" file in each deploy, but the first time? how to generate `secret.yml` the first time?

Answer (score 7):

You have to add to your .gitignore file:

```
/config/secrets.yml
```

the cap task:

```
task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
end
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"
```

The .yml file in the shared folder I usually create it myself.

Comment: hmm, 'myself' part is what I am asking about, do I have to create myself that file?

Comment: @juanpastats, yes you have to create that file, something like `scp /config/secrets.yml you@yourserver:/var/www/yourapp/shared/config/secrets.yml` will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using capistrano v3.x, you can easily use the `:linked_files` configuration variable to achieve this.

You can safely add `config/secrets.yml` to `.gitignore` and use capistrano's `:linked_files` configuration variable.

capistrano generally adds a template line with `config/database.yml` and the `config/secrets.yml` to the array when you `cap install`. You just have to uncomment that line that looks like :
`set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')`

Regarding how to generate the `secrets.yml` file for the first time (it is a one-time task of course), you do have to run `rake secret` and put the secret key generated out of it, in the file. It looks like this :

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <some alphanumeric hash>
  some_key: 338a3312d82
  some_secret: f5d9c3214e7b
  other_environment: development
  other_password: password

production:
  secret_key_base: <the key generated with `rake secret`>
  some_key: 338a3312d82
  some_secret: f5d9c3214e7b
  other_environment: development
  other_password: password
```